# Sanitize? When it doesn't output as HTML nor go into an SQL query

Tags: php, sanitization

After looking through some sites (eg https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) I found no EXPLICIT mention of what hazards the following process would open me up to;

A user answers a multiple choice question. Sending a form with the "answer" as a hidden field.

The .php page takes it (validates it to have less than 100 characters), then takes the Correct Answer from the database. It compares the two (using == comparison operator).

then sends

```
 echo "Wrong! The correct answer is ".$correctAnswer; //a hack presumably will always be wrong!!!
```

Basically, what damage could there possibly be with letting userinput (up to 100 characters) get stuck into

```
$playersAnswer = $_POST['checkAnswer'];
```

and

```
 if ($correctAnswer == $playersAnswer){ ....etc
```

The advantage for me is that I need not worry about any letters/symbols/characters in the user's answer being stripped or converted. Therefore I can use questions with full punctuation, foreign languages and even questions about javascript wwithout fear!

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: "what hazards the following process would open meup to" and "Basically what dammage could there be..."

Comment: Voting bad fit. See [the FAQ about the types of questions to be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) - `there is no actual problem to be solved: "I’m curious if other people feel like I do."`.  The way this is worded, it seems like you've already answered your own question.

Comment: The question is "Is there a need to sanitize when user input data is neither outputted nor  sent to a database?" which is the title, the rest is just to set the context

Comment: @Mario your links address output and not any possible (new) hacks that DON'T rely on html output or mysql queries, i'd read one of them already, thanks though!

Comment: @Merlyn that seems ridiculous - doesn't that mean we can't ask whether there is a problem with something if the answer is that there's indeed no problem? Although I see what you mean. Hmm.

Comment: @AdamNarbutt: Still kind of reads like a rant to me disguised as a question.  Tho if you're asking in earnest I'll take your word on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you do is use the POST variable in a comparison:

```
$correctAnswer == $playersAnswer
```

there is no danger to this.

The danger begins where you *use* the variable - in HTML output, in a database query, in an `exec()` or `eval()` command.....

Comment: Ok, that is what I was thinking. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: ...but you are using `$correctAnswer` in the html output and therefore it has to be sanitized and/or encoded (depending on e.g. whether you want to allow html code that is interpreted as such in that variable).

Comment: @VollerK All questions in the database are entered/vetted by us before being entered manually and not  via the website, the database itself would have to be hacked to mess around with $correctAnswer. But yes you're right.

Comment: @Pekka Why would the following not be dangerous? 
form name 'answer' value '1; ?> bad code '
so
     $variable = ['answer'];
becomes
     $variable = 1; ?> bad code etc
why isnt this a problem? Thanks for any hep!

Comment: @Adam because the `?>` will never be executed in a comparison. It is just a bunch of meaningless characters. It might be a problem if used in `eval()`, for example

Comment: @Pekka Thanks again,  I always imagined the variable value physically 'replacing' the $value in the code, so i guess that was my naivity and the reason for my question/doubt. Thx and Merry Xmas!